# Tensorflow set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES within jupyter

Tags: python, environment-variables, tensorflow

I have two GPUs and would like to run two different networks via ipynb simultaneously, however the first notebook always allocates both GPUs.

Using CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES, I can hide devices for python files, however I am unsure of how to do so within a notebook.

Is there anyway to hide different GPUs in to notebooks running on the same server?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can set environment variables in the notebook using `os.environ`. Do the following before initializing TensorFlow to limit TensorFlow to first GPU.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```

You can double check that you have the correct devices visible to TF

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

I tend to use it from utility module like [notebook_util](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/notebook_util.py)

```
import notebook_util
notebook_util.pick_gpu_lowest_memory()
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: for me it didn't work os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0" ...
I changed it to os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="" and then it worked. 
I'm using tensorflow 1.12

Comment: I tried displaying tensorflow local devices as mentioned. My system outputs only device type: CPU. Does this mean that tensorflow is not running GPU.

Comment: This does not work for me after tensorflow imports.

Comment: That has to be done at the very beginning of your notebook.

Answer (score 48):

You can do it faster without any imports just by using [magics](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html):

```
%env CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID
%env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

Notice that all env variable are strings, so no need to use `"`. You can verify that env-variable is set up by running: `%env <name_of_var>`. Or check all of them with `%env`.

Comment: Does this `env` setting affect other python scripts? as it looks like changing the environment variable of os.

Comment: @JenkinsY you can easily check it by setting the variable in one script and reading it in another.

Answer (score 15):

You can also enable multiple GPU cores, like so:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,2,3,4"
```