# Keras taking too long, don't know if I am using GPU or CPU

Tags: python, keras, tensor

I am getting this information when I run my program:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
    WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
    W0723 16:10:32.496439 139881743095616 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/merry/anaconda3/envs/merry_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:74: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

    W0723 16:10:32.497687 139881743095616 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/merry/anaconda3/envs/merry_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:517: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

    W0723 16:10:32.500930 139881743095616 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/merry/anaconda3/envs/merry_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4138: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

    W0723 16:10:32.524909 139881743095616 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/merry/anaconda3/envs/merry_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:133: The name tf.placeholder_with_default is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder_with_default instead.

    W0723 16:10:32.530971 139881743095616 deprecation.py:506] From /home/merry/anaconda3/envs/merry_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3445: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating:
    Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
    W0723 16:10:32.584314 139881743095616 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/merry/anaconda3/envs/merry_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:174: The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.

    2019-07-23 16:10:32.584575: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
    To enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
    2019-07-23 16:10:32.607060: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3400080000 Hz
    2019-07-23 16:10:32.607412: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x235e0b0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
    2019-07-23 16:10:32.607427: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
    OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
    OMP: Info #210: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
    OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0-7
    OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 8 available OS procs
    OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
    OMP: Info #179: KMP_AFFINITY: 1 packages x 4 cores/pkg x 2 threads/core (4 total cores)
    OMP: Info #214: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map:
    OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0 core 0 thread 0 
    OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 4 maps to package 0 core 0 thread 1 
    OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 1 maps to package 0 core 1 thread 0 
    OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 5 maps to package 0 core 1 thread 1 
    OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 2 maps to package 0 core 2 thread 0 
    OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 6 maps to package 0 core 2 thread 1 
    OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 3 maps to package 0 core 3 thread 0 
    OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 7 maps to package 0 core 3 thread 1 
    OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 6324 tid 6324 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0
    2019-07-23 16:10:32.607860: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
    2019-07-23 16:10:32.659852: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
    W0723 16:10:32.681015 139881743095616 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/merry/anaconda3/envs/merry_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1834: The name tf.nn.fused_batch_norm is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.nn.fused_batch_norm instead.

    W0723 16:10:33.686542 139881743095616 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /home/merry/anaconda3/envs/merry_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py:790: The name tf.train.Optimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer instead.
```

I don't know what is all of that, the OMP lines and I don't know whether I am using GPU or not.

The main point is that since I get this messages the execution is taking longer than I can afford it to, so I am trying to understand it in order to solve it.

Any idea of what it could be, whether I am using GPU, why it ii taking so long or how to specify a GPU?

I can add my code if it is needed.

Comment: What tensorflow package did you install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether GPU is available by:

1. In Bash shell, run `nvidia-smi`. If you have GPU (and also its drivers), you will see how many GPUs you have and other information such as the memory.
2. In tensorflow, run

```
python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
```

If it is false, you might have to check whether you have properly installed tensorflow-gpu and cuda.

Comment: This API might be more direct: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available

Comment: And if I have more than one GPU, how do I specify which one I want to use?

Comment: What I am always doing is to set the environment variable, CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893755/tensorflow-set-cuda-visible-devices-within-jupyter

Answer (score 2):

Looks like tensorflow is trying to use the CPU.
Did you install tensorflow-gpu ?

(pip install tensorflow-gpu)

Comment: I don't know if this is a dump question but should I uninstall tensorflow to install tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: I would recommend you do, yes