# How to limit visible devices in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I am working on a server with several GPUs, and I want to select one with enough free space.
With pytorch, I found that it can be done by simply setting the os environment variable "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" to the desired GPUs, but for some reason the same approach isn't working with tensorflow.

I found this solution:

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "desired_GPU_no"
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, as running `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` shows all GPUs, not the ones I select.

Later on in my code, I build a tf.keras.layers.Embedding layer, and it fails because it automatically checks for space on GPU 0, which is occupied.

Are there any more reliable ways to choose the GPU I need, or am I doing something wrong with the current solution?

I should also specify that I am working on a jupyter notebook, maybe that is causing issues?

Comment: A quick google search of "TF select GPU" brought this: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#using_a_single_gpu_on_a_multi-gpu_system

Answer (score 0):

I use this, but I cannot confirm if it works with Jupyter notebooks or not.

```
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0" # or "1", "2", "3", ...
```

Here's a related question with some additional Jupyter stuff mentioned: [Tensorflow set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES within jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893755/tensorflow-set-cuda-visible-devices-within-jupyter)